# Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: The contract verification failed. Reason: Fail - Unable to verify (solidity 0.8.4)

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I am encounter error during hardhat verify contract .would anyone pls help ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71386192/error-in-plugin-nomiclabs-hardhat-etherscan-the-contract-verification-failed